# For some columns n_distinct has a negative value

Tags: postgresql

Looking at the `pg_stats`, for some columns the `n_distinct` value is -1. What does this mean? I couldn't find an answer in the docs or anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-1 indicates a unique column in which the number of distinct values is the same as the number of rows.

> n_distinct float4
>
> If greater than zero, the estimated number of distinct values in the
> column. If less than zero, the negative of the number of distinct
> values divided by the number of rows. (The negated form is used when
> ANALYZE believes that the number of distinct values is likely to
> increase as the table grows; the positive form is used when the column
> seems to have a fixed number of possible values.) For example, -1
> indicates a unique column in which the number of distinct values is
> the same as the number of rows.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html